# Is removing "old" JSONP script tags a good practice?

Tags: javascript, jsonp

If a program might create multiple `<script>` elements for JSONP calls, is it a good practice to remove the old ones, before appending any more? Why?

Saving the created element in  a variable isn't an option in my case.

## Example

If you **don't** delete previous calls, the result may look at the end like this (or multiplied by a thousand times):

```
<script src="https://example.com/script1"></script>
<script src="https://example.com/script2"></script>
<script src="https://example.com/script3"></script>
```

But if you **do** delete previous calls, it's necessary to set an `id` for the script:

```
<script id="jsonp-call" src="https://example.com/script1"></script>
<!-- Then it'll become -->
<script id="jsonp-call" src="https://example.com/script2"></script>
<!-- And after that -->
<script id="jsonp-call" src="https://example.com/script3"></script>
```

Comment: I'm not sure it's often good practice to use JSONP in 2016

Comment: @DenysSéguret What other techniques do you suggest for avoiding CORS-related problems like this?

Comment: @Hewbot: It's not a CORS-related problem, it's an SOP-related problem to which CORS ([Cross-Origin Resource Sharing](http://www.w3.org/TR/access-control/)) can sometimes be the answer. Ideally, use JSONP only when you can't use CORS, and **only** with a very-well-trusted other domain.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Okay, let's say I don't fully trust the other domain. How should I gather their JSON?

Comment: @Hewbot: You see if they have a CORS-enabled endpoint returning JSON (not JSONP) and use ajax to query it. If they do, you're set. If they don't, and you don't trust them, then you probably don't want to let them put any code they want on your site (which is what JSONP boils down to). If they have a JSON (not JSONP) feed that *isn't* CORS-enabled, you'll want to have your page query **your** server, which in turn queries it from their server, validates that it's real JSON, and returns it to you. Of course, they may block your server's IP; if they wanted to share, they'd enable CORS.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Got it! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `script` tag is purely a transport mechanism when used for JSONP, I would clean it up as soon as it's done its job: In the JSONP callback, or when it times out. So I wouldn't leave them lying around, and I wouldn't wait until the next call to clean up the previous one.